# nested dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

How do I create a nested dictionary in python
So, I want the data be in this form..

```
{Category_id: {Product_id:... productInstance},{prod_id_1: this instance}}
```

Basically if i do something like this
lets say I want to check whether the

```
product_id = 5 is in category 1.
```

so if I do

```
Dict[1].has_key(5)--> be true or false..
```

My bad code is

```
fin = readFile(db)
categoryDict = defaultdict(list)
itemDict ={}
for line in fin:
    itemInstance = setItemInstances(line)

    itemDict[itemInstance._product_id] = itemInstance
    categoryDict[itemInstance._category_id].append(itemDict)




EDIT: example
dict = {1: { p_id: p_instance_1,
           p_id_2: p_ins_2}
     2:{ p_in_this_cat_id: this isntance}}
```

THanks

Comment: Do you want `{Category_id: {Product_id:... productInstance}{prod_id_1: this instance}}` (with a colon after `Category_id`)?

Comment: oh yeah.. sorry my bad.. i will edit the desc..

Comment: Please, show us a _valid Python example_ of what you want the dictionary to look like. Do you mean `{1: {2: productInstance, 3: productInstance2, ...}, 4: {...}}` where 1 and 4 are category ids and 2 and 3 are product ids?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is closer to what you want:

```
fin = readFile(db)
categoryDict = defaultdict(dict)     # automatically create a subdict
for line in fin:
    itemDict = {}                    # a new innermost dict for every item
    itemInstance = setItemInstances(line)
    itemDict[itemInstance._product_id] = itemInstance
    categoryDict[itemInstance._category_id] = itemDict
```

Answer (score 1):

Dicts in python are basically always a "collection" of "items";  each "item" is a key and a value, separated by a colon, and each item is separated by the next with a comma.  An item cannot have more than one key or value, but you can have collections as keys or values.

Looking at your second example:

```
dict = {1: { p_id: p_instance_1,
           p_id_2: p_ins_2}
     2:{ p_in_this_cat_id: this isntance}}
```

the outer dict needs another comma, between the end of the first item (with key `1`) and second (with key `2`).

Additionally, it's not quite clear what `this instance` is meant to mean, but it is often the case that methods on objects are passed the object itself as first parameter, and by convention, that's called `self`, but can be given any name (and this is sometimes done to reduce confusion, such as with metaclasses)

Finally; bare words, `p_id` and so forth, are rarely valid unless they are a variable name (assigned to earlier) or an attribute of another object (possibly `self.p_id`).  I don't know if that's the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

Check my NestedDict class here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16296144/2334951

```
>>> branches = [b for b in data.paths()]
>>> ['plumbers' in k for k in branches]
[True, False, True, False, False, False]
>>> any(['plumbers' in k for k in branches])
True
>>> [k for k in branches if 'plumbers' in k]
[['new york', 'queens county', 'plumbers'], ['new jersey', 'mercer county', 'plumbers']]
>>> [data[k] for k in branches if 'plumbers' in k]
[9, 3]
```

I hope that with some intuition this example covers the question.