# How to compare list of objects for a matching value?

Tags: python, list, csv, object

I have a list of products which contains many objects having properties like id,image_url. As you can see below:

**total_products**

`[{u'image_url': u'https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCG1ObwtCgqxZIk&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgigya.jp%2Fdpa%2F1000000.png&cfs=1&_nc_hash=AQAPdo31zo9WJk8j', u'id': u'1539966686030963', u'retailer_id': u'product-1000000'}, {u'image_url': u'https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDyc-Yyic5QLOqH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgigya.jp%2Fdpa%2F0.png&cfs=1&_nc_hash=AQDhmhPJxFZEpMFX', u'id': u'993388404100117', u'retailer_id': u'product-0'}, {u'image_url': u'https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAwTzrzAjdKFjmB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgigya.jp%2Fdpa%2F1000.png&cfs=1&_nc_hash=AQCMMJRJ_r7QB06I', u'id': u'642820939176165', u'retailer_id': u'product-1000'}, {u'image_url': u'https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBHdbRqB7F6aMKM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgigya.jp%2Fdpa%2F1.png&cfs=1&_nc_hash=AQDx7P52g0NYBB-3', u'id': u'1411912028843607', u'retailer_id': u'product-1'}, {u'image_url': u'https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQB7aSPmk_j21umz&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgigya.jp%2Fdpa%2F100000.png&cfs=1&_nc_hash=AQAPV5oe_ymaAcXr', u'id': u'942522339181104', u'retailer_id': u'product-100000'}, {u'image_url': u'https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQB69V2cgASUIci1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgigya.jp%2Fdpa%2F100.png&cfs=1&_nc_hash=AQAk3eZ4vqWYbOW4', u'id': u'1347112758661660', u'retailer_id': u'product-100'}, {u'image_url': u'https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQD44rjEUMk6Yp2H&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgigya.jp%2Fdpa%2F1000001.png&cfs=1&_nc_hash=AQBT_0iB417B08ux', u'id': u'1354204821311003', u'retailer_id': u'product-1000001'}, {u'image_url': u'https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQB4ucqXEbo2DyC7&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgigya.jp%2Fdpa%2F1000002.png&cfs=1&_nc_hash=AQAQ2vuj0WmuXSqw', u'id': u'1776841739008769', u'retailer_id': u'product-1000002'}, {u'image_url': u'https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBM75VZTNuxqaoq&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgigya.jp%2Fdpa%2F10.png&cfs=1&_nc_hash=AQAUdkc6II5eu47D', u'id': u'1358784964179738', u'retailer_id': u'product-10'}, {u'image_url': u'https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAY0kmVnHXBbhHe&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgigya.jp%2Fdpa%2F10000.png&cfs=1&l&_nc_hash=AQCT1PHl5h1Rhc5r', u'id': u'1337513966312571', u'retailer_id': u'product-10000'}]`

I am reading a csv file which contains data like below;-

**csv_file_data:**
[image]

As you can see id the in the csv_file `id` and `retailer_id` are same for some products-
so I want to change the `image_link` in `csv file` if `retailer_id` and `id` matches.

In doing so I am reading csv file row by row and looping through all the products in `total_products` and if any match is found change `image_link`

**Code:**

```
def update_csv(file): 
    print file
    reader  = csv.DictReader(open(file))
    out_file_name = str(file).replace(".csv", "")
    writer = csv.DictWriter(open(out_file_name+"_updated.csv","wb"),fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for current_row in reader:
        for product in total_products:
            retailer_id = product['retailer_id']
            if(current_row['id']==retailer_id):
                current_row['image_link']= "RajSharma"
                print "Match = "+str(retailer_id)+" in "+file
                break   
        writer.writerow(current_row)
```

The problem with this approach is if `total_products` contains more than 1000-10,000 it's taking too long to run.

Is there way to find `retailer_id` in `total_products` and if so change `image_link`?

Comment: Convert `total_products` into a dictionary, so you don't have to loop over it for every line.

Comment: @Barmar  can you give some example how to covert and use..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586179/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-nested-dictionary

Comment: After you convert it, just replace the loop with `found_product = products_dict[retailer_id]`

Comment: @Barmar Converting to a dict isn't needed if the user just wants to check for values against a shared key. Converting to a set of just the ID's would suffice. Only if the user needed to know other information in the dict, would converting to a large dict be necessary.

Comment: @Vincenzzzochi Good point, I thought he was pulling something from the objects. But a set is essentially just a dictionary with no values.

Comment: I suggest that profile your script and see where it's spending most of its time and then try to optimize that portion. See [_How can you profile a script?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-script)

Comment: @martineau I'll try to profile script from next time onward. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create a set of ids from `total_products`:

```
product_ids = set([product['retailer_id'] for product in total_products])
```

Then, check if the `current_row['id']` is in the set:

```
for current_row in reader:
    if current_row['id'] in product_ids:
        current_row['image_link'] = 'RajSharma'
```

A set is much faster to search through, and we only need a list of unique product ID's to check against. 
Using `if current_row['image_link'] in product_ids` leverages the underlying C code for looping which optimizes checking for a value in the set.